# time series barplot in R

Tags: r, time-series

i have a time series data like this:

```
x <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1264572000, 1266202800, 1277362800, 
1277456400, 1277859600, 1278032400, 1260370800, 1260892800, 1262624400, 
1262707200), class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = ""), data = c(-0.00183760994446658, 
0.00089738603087497, 0.000423513598318936, 0, -0.00216496690393131, 
-0.00434836817931339, -0.0224199153445617, 0.000583823085470003, 
0.000353088613905206, 0.000470295331234771)), .Names = c("date", 
"data"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
), class = "data.frame")
```

and I will make a barplot of this dataset whereby each bar stands for each date (if there are no datas for timespan, there should be gaps).

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: +1 For using `dput` to recreate your data.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `ggplot`:  (Note that you have to provide `stat="identity"` to `geom_bar` to prevent it from summarising the data and creating a histogram).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(x=date, y=data)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

And if you are inclined to use base graphics:

```
plot(x$date, x$data, type="h")
```

[image]